# InterVLAN between namespaces using a third namespace as a router

Tags: linux, namespace, vlan

I need to establish connection between 2 namespaces (one has `ip add 10.0.0.1/24 gateway 10.0.0.254` and the other one has `ip add 20.0.0.1/24 gateway 20.0.0.254`), separated in different VLANs (10 and 20); they are connected to an OVS bridge, and the third namespace has to act as a router -- is it possible? This one is connected to the bridge in two interfaces. I assigned to interface gw1 10.0.0.254 and the other interface gw2 20.0.0.254. I did manage to get a ICMP reply when I didn't assign a VLAN tag to the interface between the bridge and the namespace1 and also to the gw1, but when I assign one VLAN tag to the port of the switch nothing happens, just a "Destination host unreachable". When I use wireshark, it seems like ARP is not getting an answer. What am I missing?

Creating namespaces:

```
sudo ip netns add namespace1
sudo ip netns add namespace2
sudo ip netns add router
```

Creating the links:

```
sudo ip link add vif1 type veth peer name ethns1
sudo ip link add vif2 type veth peer name ethns2
sudo ip link add vif11 type veth peer name gw1
sudo ip link add vif22 type veth peer name gw2
```

Creating the ovs bridge and attaching the ports:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br switch
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port switch vif1
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port switch vif11
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port switch vif2
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port switch vif22
```

Attaching the veths to the namespaces:

```
sudo ip link set dev ethns1 netns namespace1
sudo ip link set dev ethns2 netns namespace2
sudo ip link set dev gw1 netns router
sudo ip link set dev gw2 netns router
```

Configuring the addresses of the namespaces:

```
sudo ip netns exec namespace1 ifconfig ethns1 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sudo ip netns exec namespace1 route add default gw 10.0.0.254
sudo ip netns exec namespace2 ifconfig ethns2 20.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sudo ip netns exec namespace2 route add default gw 20.0.0.254
sudo ip netns exec router ifconfig gw1 10.0.0.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sudo ip netns exec router ifconfig gw2 20.0.0.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Setting up the interfaces:

```
sudo ip link set dev vif1 up
sudo ip link set dev vif2 up
sudo ip link set dev vif11 up
sudo ip link set dev vif22 up
```

Enabling IP Forwarding in namespace 3 (the router):

```
sudo ip netns exec router sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I still didn't add the VLAN tags to the ports of the switch, and I can get from namespace1 to the gw1, but when I do this:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl -- set port vif1 tag=10
sudo ovs-vsctl -- set port vif2 tag=20
```

I'm not sure about this two.

```
sudo ovs-vsctl -- set port vif22 trunk=10,20 
sudo ovs-vsctl -- set port vif11 trunk=10,20
```

And then nothing happens :(

I'm still a new guy working with Ubuntu, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Is the point of the exercise to use the OVS bridge with tagging? (Because I am not entirely clear on what exactly OVS does when the tag option is set). If OVS adds VLAN tags to the outgoing traffic on the ports, then *inside* all namespaces where you use the ports you need to "untag" them with an additional interface, as in `ip link add ... type vlan id 10` etc. You use then this interface instead of the original interface. If you don't need an OVS bridge, and a normal bridge will do, I can describe the setup. Also, please stick to IP private ranges (`10.1.0.*/24` instead of `20.0.0.*/24`).

Comment: Also since you want your router to receive tagged packets, only one interface (and one bridge port) is needed (and then two vlan sub interfaces like dirkt told). Your setting has two trunking bridge ports with the same vlans for the router, which will only add confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Not having used Open vSwitch before, I now had to play around with this.

The key information is in `man 5 ovs-vswitchd.conf.db`, where the various `vlan_mode` are explained.

In particular, for an **access** port, inside the switch the packet is always tagged, outside of the switch it is untagged, and on ingress the tag gets added, while on egress it gets removed. That was what I suspected after your description, but it's nice to make sure.

So to implement your scenario with access ports only, I used three namespaces `ns0` (router), `ns1` and `ns2` like this:

```
ns0:
  veth0b (peer veth0a), 10.0.10.254/24
  veth0d (peer veth0c), 10.0.20.254/24

ns1:
  veth1b (peer veth1a), 10.0.10.1/24

ns2:
  veth2b (peer veth2a), 10.0.20.1/24

main namespace:
  br0 (ovs):
    veth0a (access, tag=100)
    veth0c (access, tag=200)
    veth1a (access, tag=100)
    veth2a (access, tag=200)
```

It's extremely convient to start an `xterm` in each namespace (I prefer a colored background), then you can also debug packet flow with `tcpdump` inside the namespace.

Create namespaces, create veth-pairs, move into namespaces as required, don't forget to `set` each link `up`. Then

In `ns0`:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.10.254/24 dev veth0b
sudo ip addr add 10.0.20.254/24 dev veth0d
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

In `ns1`:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.10.1/24 dev veth1b
sudo ip route add default via 10.0.10.254
```

In `ns2`:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.20.1/24 dev veth2b
sudo ip route add default via 10.0.20.254
```

In the main namespace:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth0a tag=100
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth0c tag=200
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth1a tag=100
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth2a tag=200
```

Now in each namespace the ping's should work, first test the direct partner, then the routed partner.

We can also replace the two access port veth-pairs with a single **trunked** veth-pair. It's not necessary to add the `trunk=100,200`, because by default each non-access port is a trunked port for all VLANs.

In the main namespace:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl del-port br0 veth0a
sudo ovs-vsctl del-port br0 veth0c
sudo ip link del veth0a
sudo ip link del veth0c
sudo ip link add veth0a type veth peer name veth0b netns ns0
sudo ip link set veth0a up
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth0a
```

In `ns0`:

```
sudo ip link add link veth0b name veth0b.100 type vlan id 100
sudo ip link add link veth0b name veth0b.200 type vlan id 200
sudo ip link set veth0b up
sudo ip addr add 10.0.10.254/24 dev veth0b.100
sudo ip addr add 10.0.20.254/24 dev veth0b.200
```

Then test like above.

Comment: Check with `ip addr` that you've added the address, and with `ip route` that adding the address has added a route on this interface to the subnet (which *should* happen automatically).

Comment: `tee` is the variant for `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` when I have to use `sudo` (I was to lazy to edit out those `sudo`s). `sysctl` effectively uses the `/proc` filesystem to do the same thing, but can also process configuration files to make those settings permanent (as in "executed on boot").

Comment: The interface name is missing in `ifconfig`. I am also not sure why you insist on using the old `ifconfig`. If you use `ip addr add ...` instead, you can also shorten the call into the network namespace to `ip -n ns1 addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev your_if` (whatever the interface name is) instead of using `ip netns exec ns1 ...`.

Comment: It's difficult to do remote debugging like this... If `ip addr add` doesn't do exactly the same as `ifconfig`, then something is very weird on your system.